# How to include Date in log4j configuration

Tags: java, properties, log4j

here is the current logging which I am seeing in Server:

```
12:40:10,190 | INFO  | -549263035-19951 | ServiceImpl    | Upload started
12:40:12,912 | INFO  | -549263035-19960 | ServiceImpl    | Upload started
12:40:12,915 | INFO  | -549263035-19958 | ServiceImpl    | Upload started

My application is using log4j to implement logging. here is the log4j.properties file which is sitting inside META-INF. 

log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, O
log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.O.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.O.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n


As we can clearly see, current logging has the time information for every event. I wanted to know if there is a way I could make some changes in this properties file or elsewhere to include the full timestamp i.e. Date and time both.
```

something like : 
2013-07-18 12:40:12 | INFO  | -549263035-19958 | ServiceImpl    | Upload started

```
Thanks for suggestion.
```

Comment: I have feelings that your logger message uses not that layout you posted, could you change your pattern somehow (delete [%d{ISO8601}] for example) and make sure your logging output will change.

Comment: i went through the documentation and it seems like you were right that my log doesnt use this layout. because %d followed by ISO8601 should have captured the date as well. I am assuming the server where I deployed this application is using different logging scheme which takes precedence over it. but I dont know how to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. 
this application was deployed in Servicemix container. Apparantly inside servicemix's installation directory I found this configuration file. 
"/usr/local/servicemix/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg".

Inside this file, there was a SiftingAppender which was using %d[ABSOLUTE] as a conversion pattern. So basically every bundle which is deployed under servicemix is going to use this "siftingappender" properties. I just removed [ABSOLUTE] from this configuration file and started getting the Date in my logs.